# When can I create a norm from a function $g:\{1, ..., n\} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on something where I can specify a function $g:\{1, ..., N\} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ where we interpret $g(n)$ as the "length" of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $n$ entries as $1$ and $N - n$ entries as $0$. I'm trying to see when such a $g$ can be converted into a norm on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

I was thinking of trying to do the trick where you can specify a convex shape around the origin and interpret these as the unit vectors. But, I'm not sure when this is possible. For example, I think that if $N = 2$ and we specify $g(1) = 10$ and $g(2) = 1$ then we can't make a convex hull around the origin going through the eight points:

$$(1/10, 0), (1/2, 1/2), (0, 1/10), (-1/2, 1/2), (-1/10, 0), (-1/2, -1/2), (0, -1/10), (1/2, -1/2)$$

although I'm not even sure about this.

Can anyone help me figure out when $g$ specifies a norm?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is the following:

Given a positive integer $N$ and a function $g:\{1,\ldots,N\}\to\Bbb R_+$, define a norm $\|\cdot\|_g$ on $\Bbb R^N$ such that $\|e_k\|_g=g(k)$ for $1\le k\le N$, where $e_k=(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{k-1},1,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{N-k})$ with $1$ at $k$th position.

If that is the case,
$$\|(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N)\|_g=\sum_{k=1}^Ng(k)|a_k|$$
should work.

My knowledge about inequalities is a bit rusty, buth I think that for a real $p\ge1$
$$\|(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N)\|_{g,p}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^Ng(k)|a_k|^p\right)^{1/p}$$
is also a norm. (The Eucidean norm is for constant $g(k)=1$ and $p=2$).

Anyway $g$ is not a norm, but a function that describes the 'weight' you give to each dimension. A norm is a function on a vector space, and $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ is no vector space (it has not even zero).

Comment: Thanks! That's not quite what I was looking for. You can see it as: let $i_1, ..., i_k$ be distinct elements of $\{1, ..., N\}$. I want a norm, $\| \cdot \|_g$ such that $\| e_{i_1} + \cdots + e_{i_k}\|_g = g(k)$.